# Onclick doesn't trigger Jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick

This is the first time i have this issue and i don't understand why. I have a trigger click() with Jquery like this :

```
$('.history-element').click(function () {
    console.log("Trigger");
    detailHistory($(this).attr('historyNumber'));
});
```

This is the element i'm triggering :

```
<span style="cursor: pointer" class="history-element" historynumber="1">14/09/18 15:19</span>
<i style=" float: right" class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Accept" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

When i try to run a minimal code on JSFiddle that's work, so the issue is about something else but i don't find what ! Do you know what could create a conflict whith onclick ?

Thank's !

**EDIT**

This is the detailHistory function :

```
function detailHistory(index){
    var history = Office.context.roamingSettings.get('history');
    $('#historyRecapArea').hide();

    $('#historyExpeditor').html(history[index]['expeditor']);
    $('#historyMessage').html(history[index]['content']);
    $('#recapType').html(history[index]['type']);

    if(history[index]['type'] === "Confirmation"){
        $('#recapConfLabel').html("Message envoyé le :");
        $('#recapDate').html(history[index]['date']);
    }
    else if(history[index]['type'] === "Rappel"){
        $('#recapConfLabel').html("Message configuré le :");
        $('#recapDate').html(history[index]['date']);
    }
    else{
        $('#historyRecapArea').show();
        return;
    }

    $('#historyDetails').show();
}
```

Comment: You would need to include the detailHistory function as well. is there a piece of code that is returning false or breaking the JS from continuing. look at your console for more hints.

Comment: Hi @md123 thank's for you reply. There is nothing in the console, no error, no warning.

Comment: Do you assign the click event handler inside a document ready handler?  JSFiddle does that by default, which would explain why it works there.

Comment: The `history-element` isn't created dynamically?

Comment: Hi @Archer I'm not sure to understand. I have two JS file, one where Jquery is initialize and who importe another JS file (The imported file contains these functions).

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Yes history-element are created dynamically

Comment: So try event delegation `on()` like `$('body').on('click','.history-element', function () {`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution thank's to the comments.

I was select .history-elements class before creating them. Now, i just set the click handler after and it's work.

Comment: Please delete this answer - just use the comments under the question for things like this :)

Comment: @Archer https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Taplar I assume you didn't read the question and comments, where this was suggested to him.  Anyway, it's a question duplicated almost as much as *"How do I return values from async methods?"*  This is not a self-answered question.

Comment: Regardless, the site does not prohibit users from answering their own questions, as that link reflects.  You can dislike how a user gets to the point that they answer their own question, but that doesn't mean the site prohibits it. @Archer

Comment: @Taplar - this is a comment, not an answer.  I don't see any value in this post whatsoever, as an answer.  Do you honestly believe that this would help someone who found this question, with the same issue?